# Android: Calculate correct Azimuth while compensating for Pitch/Tilt changes (Device not flat)

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, screen-orientation, azimuth

I'm currently programming an Android camera application (on my Samsung S9 running on Android 9) and I am noticing an issue for the outputted azimuth value when the device has been tilted (is not flat). The difference in degrees from when the device starts off flat and rises to near a 90 degree angle for example can vary from up to 10 or 20 so degrees.

I have been scouring various StackOverflow threads but none seem to have a solution which involves the device potentially using all possible rotations in combination with the ROTATION_VECTOR sensor. The reason why I went with ROTATION_VECTOR is mainly because from one of the threads I've read, users mentioned it taking in to consideration of potential changes in pitch/tilt for azimuth calculations but this is clearly not the case for my issue here.

I also understand that this sensor requires devices to have the Gyroscope sensor available but for my purposes, this will always be the case.

The outputted azimuth value appears to be correct when the device is parallel to the ground (layed flat on the floor) but as soon as it becomes tilted but kept in the same facing direction, the azimuth begins to gradually increase/decrease. This is the same for any rotation case whether the phone is in Portrait or Landscape mode.

The method below is called inside the onSensorChanged event:

```
private float[] calculateOrientation(float[] values) {
        float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
        float[] remappedMatrix = new float[9];
        float[] orientation = new float[3];

        // Determine the rotation matrix
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, values);

        // Remap the coordinates based on the natural device orientation.
        int x_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_X;
        int y_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_Y;

        switch (screenRotation) {
            case (Surface.ROTATION_90):
                x_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_Y;
                y_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X;
                break;

            case (Surface.ROTATION_180):
                y_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y;
                break;

            case (Surface.ROTATION_270):
                x_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Y;
                y_axis = SensorManager.AXIS_X;
                break;
            default: break;
        }

        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, x_axis, y_axis, remappedMatrix);

        // Obtain the current, corrected orientation.
        SensorManager.getOrientation(remappedMatrix, orientation);

        angleLowPassFilter.add(orientation[0]);

        // Convert from Radians to Degrees.
        values[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]);
        values[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]);
        values[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[2]);

        int correctedAzimuth = (int) ((values[0] + 360) % 360);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "Azimuth: [%s]", correctedAzimuth));

        return values;
    }
```